# Currying: appending two lists

Tags: list, scala, append, currying

I am trying to understand currying in scala. The code takes two lists and appends them.

```
  def append(as:List[Int],bs:List[Int]):List[Int]=as match{

  case Nil=>bs
  case x::xs=> x::append(xs,bs)

}
```

But If I want to write currying version of it:

```
def cappend(as:List[Int])(bs:List[Int])=as match{
     case Nil=>bs
     case x::xs=> x::cappend(xs,bs)
   }
```

Would that be correct?

Comment: Yes, the only thing is you need x::append(xs)(bs) and not x::append(xs,bs)

Answer (score 3):

In currying you can define partially applied functions so there is no need to pass all parameters at once. In the example, consider the following corrections,

```
def cappend(as:List[Int])(bs:List[Int]): List[Int] = as match {
     case Nil   => bs
     case x::xs => x::cappend(xs)(bs)
   }
```

Namely, each parameter is wrapped in parentheses (also the recursive function needs return type, the recursive call was missing a prefixing c). Then, we define a partially defined function

```
val a = cappend(List(1,2)) _
a: List[Int] => List[Int] = <function1>
```

that will append `List(1,2)` to whichever `List[Int]` is provided as a second parameter. For instance,

```
a(List(3,4))
res1: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Also note that we can have a more general type signature, for lists not only of `Int`,

```
def cappend[T](as:List[T])(bs:List[T]): List[T]
```